# How to append country code only in select tag vuejs2

Tags: vuejs2

I have a form which requires phone numbers with country code.
In select tag, when dropdown it should have Country name and Country code but when selected, it should be country code only. Is that possible?

Here's my code

```
<select v-model="country" data-vv-as="Country" name="country" v-validate="'required'" :class="{'select': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('register-form.country')}" data-vv-scope="register-form">
  <option disabled selected>--</option>
  <option v-for="country in countries" :value="country.id" 
   :key="country.id">{{country.name}} (+{{ country.calling_code }})
  </option>
</select>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't use `v-model="country"` and then use same variable name in `v-for="country in countries"` so use something like `v-model="selectedCountry"`
2. You need to pass country code as an option's value and not it's id.

   `<option v-for="country in countries" :value="country.calling_code" 
             :key="country.id">{{country.name}} (+{{ country.calling_code }})
    </option>`